# Using Markdown To Bypass "Link To JSFiddle" Error

Tags: discussion, review-queues, jsfiddle

While reviewing ["First Posts"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/) questions, I come across multiple cases when the OPs  deliberately use the markdowns to get around the *"Links To jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by codes"* error; more commonly by converting the URL to code.

What will be the appropriate actions for me as the reviewer?

1. Fix the URL?
2. Add a comment to the question, requesting them to include their codes?
3. Copy the code from JSFiddle for them?
4. Flag the question and get a mod to look at it?

Comment: The system should automatically correct that by extracting the code from the fiddle. But I guess we don't care anymore since we have Stack Snippets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This off-topic flag is almost always applicable to these cases:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

If you're feeling generous, add a comment. If you're feeling *really* generous, edit the question to fix the link and add the code.

Answer (score 3):

### For questions

Check the fiddle. If it looks short enough and the question adequately explains the problem, edit the question to include the code. If it looks too long, or the post itself doesn't include anything about the problem, just close the question as **unclear what you are asking**.

### For answers

Downvote/recommend deletion if the post doesn't explain anything, which is usually the case with such answers. If the answer has some adequate explanation, take a look at the code and pick out the changes to edit it in the answer.