# Please check for code more extensively when jsfiddle links are present

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

[I know this was answered before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272134/1234256), but I'm seeing more questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26187642/1234256) that just put the jsfiddle link in a code block to bypass the error.

Can it be required that `<` or `{` be present in one or more code blocks when a jsfiddle link exists? I don't believe I've seen code-formatted jsfiddle links that **do** include these symbols, or any code shown on jsfiddle that **doesn't** include either of them.

---

The question has since been edited to include the code. [Here is the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26187642/1).

Answer (score 2):

Will that really achieve anything? Like I've said before, some people are just more interested in bypassing error messages than actually putting in the effort to resolve the issue legitimately. We'll just end up with people doing `http://jsfiddle.net/... {` and still be dealing with the same problem.

The basic check catches most cases. Most importantly, **it gives them a warning** and guides new users who *are* interested in asking proper questions on how to do so. If the user is more interested in ignoring it, then there's nothing we can really do to stop them.

Comment: The fact that `<` or `{` is required *does not have to be published.* Since new users are the main concern, most probably won't figure it out immediately unless they dig through the js.

Comment: @Mooseman How ever would [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264427/html-like-layouting) figure out why the system was rejecting his question? Just a random example that doesn't include either `<` or `{`, because I was curious.

Comment: Yes, you make a good point. Perhaps 2+ blocks of code OR the presence of `<` or `{` would be better. You would get more false negatives though.

Comment: Actually, you could use a lexer to check the text to see that it is correct JavaScript syntax

Comment: @true Not everything will be JavaScript, though.